# Processing JSON Object/Array based on value

Tags: javascript, json, loops, ecmascript-6

Trying to create a function that takes its first argument a string and its second argument a JSON LIST:

```
[
    {
        "date": "09/09/18",
        "how_many": 11,
        "species": "XXXXX"
    },
    {
        "date": "04/11/17",
        "how_many": 41,
        "species": "TTTTTT"
    },
    {
        "date": "17/03/18",
        "how_many": 30,
        "species": "DDDDDDDD"
    },
    {
        "date": "17/08/18",
        "how_many": 31,
        "species": "XXXXX"
    },
]
```

If the string is present in the "species" count of each JSON entry, it would return the amount of occurrences.

Essentially, a function that returns the number of occurrences in the array (or list) of objects whose "species" key matches the first argument of the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

From Docs,

> The reduce() method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each member of the array resulting in a single output value.
>
> Your reducer function's returned value is assigned to the accumulator, whose value is remembered across each iteration throughout the array and ultimately becomes the final, single resulting value.

**EXPLANATION**

As you now know, reduce function will reduce the array into a single value which here will be the sum of all matching **species**. The default value of sum is `0`. On iterating, we check species of object against the passed species value in function. If the value matches, add its **how_many** value to the sum.

**ES6**

```js
let list = [{"date":"09/09/18","how_many":11,"species":"XXXXX"},{"date":"04/11/17","how_many":41,"species":"TTTTTT"},{"date":"17/03/18","how_many":30,"species":"DDDDDDDD"},{"date":"17/08/18","how_many":31,"species":"XXXXX"}];

function findOccurences(str, arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a,c) => a + (c.species === str ? c.how_many : 0), 0);
}

console.log(findOccurences("XXXXX", list));
```

**ES5**

```js
let list = [{"date":"09/09/18","how_many":11,"species":"XXXXX"},{"date":"04/11/17","how_many":41,"species":"TTTTTT"},{"date":"17/03/18","how_many":30,"species":"DDDDDDDD"},{"date":"17/08/18","how_many":31,"species":"XXXXX"}];

function findOccurences(str, arr) {
  // Here a - accumulator and c - current value
  return arr.reduce(function(a, c){
    // If the species of object is same as passed value (str), add it to total sum
    if(c.species === str) {
      a += c.how_many;
    }
    return a;
  }, 0);
}

console.log(findOccurences("XXXXX", list));
```

Comment: Lovely! This works. Wonder if someone can break it down for me please? I know Java but not javascript ! Lovely

Comment: @AppleFarmer - Glad to help you mate! I have added explanation and code in ES5 for better understanding. I hope I am able to explain the concept as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function getCount(str, jsonArr) {
   var match = jsonArr.filter(obj=> obj.species === str);
   return match.length;
}
```

Comment: Tried , does not work ! Returns wrong answer, sorry.

Comment: Show us your inputs, expected output and the output this function returns

Comment: Are you expecting sum of 'how_many' values when string matchs?